# How can I append facets and keep individual facet height in the plot as is?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I want to create a large `facet_wrap` with `ggplot2`.

What I want is some **automatic** way to append the individual facets by column so that the facets keep the size they would have by default if (with the same data) only the first row with four columns of facets would be supplied.

E.g. I am concerned about the plot height. I know how to manually change the plot height, but I need an automatic way.

*Some example data:*

```
mpg <- mpg %>%
distinct(model, year, .keep_all = TRUE)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=year, y=hwy))+
   geom_point()+
   facet_wrap(~model)
```

All facets should have the same height as

```
mpg %>%
  distinct(model, year, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  filter(model %in% c("4runner 4wd", "a4", "a4 quattro", "altima")) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=hwy))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~model, ncol = 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conserve plot height by using `theme(aspect.ratio)`. For example,

```
mpg <- mpg %>%
    distinct(model, year, .keep_all = TRUE)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x=year, y=hwy))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~model) + theme(aspect.ratio=2)
```

[image: aspect_ratio]